# Augmenting time series dataset - RNN (LSTM)

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, data-augmentation

I'm attempting to augment an existing time series dataset. The source of the data is an IoT sensor. My goal is to take a training dataset, of maybe 20 days (data generated on 1 hour intervals), and augment that with X number of days of synthetic data. My approach is to use RNN (LSTM) to augment the dataset. The issue I'm having is that all of the resulting values for the synthetic data are all the same. I've gone so far as to increase the training data from 20 days to 67 days and to 280 days. I've also increased the number of epochs from 100 to 200, with no success. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Note: The original data is clean (no gaps etc.), linear in nature, not intermittent missing values etc.

Here's a sample of the original data

```
timestamp,value
2013-07-04 00:00:00,69.88083514
2013-07-04 01:00:00,71.22022706
2013-07-04 02:00:00,70.87780496
2013-07-04 03:00:00,68.95939994
2013-07-04 04:00:00,69.28355102
2013-07-04 05:00:00,70.06096581
2013-07-04 06:00:00,69.27976479
2013-07-04 07:00:00,69.36960846
....
```

Results (synthetic starts AFTER 2014-03-03 09:00:00)

```
....
2014-03-02 02:00:00,65.00628144
2014-03-02 03:00:00,65.10276279
2014-03-03 09:00:00,64.73752596
....
2014-03-03 09:00:00,64.90076446533203
2014-03-03 10:00:00,65.06415557861328
2014-03-03 11:00:00,65.22787475585938
2014-03-03 12:00:00,65.39212799072266
2014-03-03 13:00:00,65.5571060180664
2014-03-03 14:00:00,65.7229995727539
2014-03-03 15:00:00,65.8899917602539
....
2014-03-09 09:00:00,85.6402587890625
2014-03-09 10:00:00,85.64026641845703
2014-03-09 11:00:00,85.64026641845703
2014-03-09 12:00:00,85.64026641845703
2014-03-09 13:00:00,85.64026641845703
2014-03-09 14:00:00,85.64026641845703
2014-03-09 15:00:00,85.64026641845703
2014-03-09 16:00:00,85.64026641845703
```

My Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

def augment_timeseries(df, num_days):

    # Create a copy of the timestamp column
    timestamp_col = df['timestamp'].copy()

    # Convert timestamp column to datetime format
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

    # Set timestamp column as the index
    df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
    
    # Get the frequency of the timestamps in the original dataset
    freq = 'H'
    
    # Create a range of timestamps with the same frequency as the original dataset
    end_time = df.index[-1] + pd.DateOffset(days=num_days)
    timestamps = pd.date_range(start=df.index[-1], end=end_time, freq=freq)

    # Reshape data for input into RNN model
    X_train = df.values.reshape((-1, 1, 1))

    # Create the RNN model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(1, 1), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    # Fit the model on the data
    model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

    # Use the model to make predictions for new timestamps
    for timestamp in timestamps:
        X_test = np.array([[df.values[-1]]])
        prediction = model.predict(X_test)

        df.loc[len(df)] = [prediction[0][0][0]]

        timestamp_df = pd.DataFrame([timestamp])
        timestamp_col = pd.concat([timestamp_col, timestamp_df], ignore_index=True)
        
        model.reset_states()

    # Add the timestamp column back to the original dataframe
    df.insert(0, 'timestamp', timestamp_col.values)

    return df
```